# Search within a string from a list of keywords and tag keywords that occur

Tags: r, string-matching

I have a set of statements

```
statement <- as.matrix(c("the cat sat on the mat", 
                          "the dog ran up the hill",
                          "the dog ran up the hill to the mat"))
```

and a list of keywords

`keywords <- as.matrix(c("cat", "mat", "dog", "hill"))`

I want to search within the statements from my list of keywords and tag what keywords occur i.e. have the result

```
statement                             keywords
the cat sat on the mat                cat, mat 
the dog ran up the hill               dog, hill
the dog ran up the hill to the mat    dog, hill, mat
```

I'm thinking one way I can do it is use grep in a way like

```
statement[grep("cat", statement$V1, ignore.case = TRUE), "keywords"] <- "cat"
statement[grep("mat", statement$V1, ignore.case = TRUE), "keywords"] <- "mat"
```

... and so on but firstly, that won't give tag for me all the keywords that occur. Secondly if I am trying to find a way of doing so when I have a large list of lets say 1000 keywords and 500 statements it will just be unwieldy.

How would you suggest one about this? Is there a way using grep or are there any packages that can mine text and return keywords from a predetermined list?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary for these to be matrix objects? Or would vectors be sufficient?

Comment: @benjamin vectors would be sufficient in this case

Comment: @DarshanBaral thanks! This is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringi` package,

```
library(stringi)
sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(statement[,1], 
                       paste(keywords[,1], collapse = '|')), toString)

#[1] "cat, mat"      "dog, hill"     "dog, hill, mat"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keywords <- c("cat", "mat", "dog", "hill")
m = sapply(keywords, grepl, statement)
       cat   mat   dog  hill
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

apply(m,1, function(y) paste0(colnames(m)[y], collapse=","))
[1] "cat,mat"      "dog,hill"     "mat,dog,hill"
```

---

or in a single line : split each row of `statement` by " " and then check using `%in%` which words were present and `paste` them all

```
apply(statement, 1, function(i) paste0(x[x %in% unlist(strsplit(i, " "))], collapse=","))
[1] "cat,mat"      "dog,hill"     "mat,dog,hill"
```